# What is this socket for?

Tags: identification, plug, socket

I need some help identifying a socket.

I have no idea what it might be.
Websites offering help to classify didnt help.

Has anybody seen such a connection before and can give me some info?
what kind of cable is needed for a connection?

The Image shows the back of the head from a Pepper Robot.

I can only guess about the dimension because it is hard to reach.

Width is around 8mm.

I assume it is used for data transfer and would like to find out if i can use it as energy source for an raspberry pi.

[image]

Comment: It's always helpful to know what kind of device that connector is on, and what you expect that connector to transport. Also, a scale would be most helpful.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Re scale: you can see a 50mm fan and an RJ45 (Ethernet) plug in the background.

Comment: What is this thing that the connector is on?

Comment: Yeah, so, how many mm is that conenctor wide, what is the device that it's attached to, and what do you assume it transports. You've answered none of my questions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like a Micro-USB AB connector, like this [Molex 47589-0001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dns1A.png) or similar:

[image: image from the datasheet]

You can connect to it using any regular microUSB A or B connectors.

---

That said, it **may not actually be used here to transport USB**, but for debug/firmware flashing (could be used for low voltage serial, perhaps?) or something entirely different.

It would help to know what this device is and also what it connects to internally – say, the lack of a differential pair connecting to it would suggest that this is likely not used for USB, for example.

Alternatively, just probe and see.

---

**Edit:** *If* this is USB, the AB connectors are/were often used for OTG hosts. You may be able to attach an adaptor cable and draw some power from it, although running a raspi from it may be pushing it.

Comment: Thanks microUSB B actually fits. I tried it before but i was convinced it wasnt usb :-)